# Kivy Creating Texture Crashes Program

Tags: python, opengl, kivy, textures

I'm currently getting into Kivy. However when I try to create a texture object by
`texture = Texture.create(size=(50,50))`
The program just terminates. PyCharm gives me

> Testing started at 20:19 ...
>
> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\dummy\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-11-03_78.txt
>
> [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
>
> [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
>
> [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
>
> [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
>
> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

but nothing more. Otherwise kivy seems to be working just fine...

thanks in advance

Comment: From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html): `Using Texture before OpenGL has been initialized will lead to a crash. If you need to create textures before the application has started, import Window first: from kivy.core.window import Window.`  Could that be your problem?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnAnderson yes, that was actually it. Thank you!